# function works on page load but not on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var names = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#selauth option').each(function(){
  names.push($(this).text());
 });
});

function givemefirst() {
 $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
 $('.postitle').eq(0).addClass('pmarked');
 givemestuff();
}

givemefirst();

function givemestuff() {
 let obj = $('.pmarked');
 $('.optemp').remove();
 let auth = obj.attr('data-auth');
 if (names.includes(auth)) {
  $('#selauth').val(auth);
 }
 else {
  $('#selauth').append("<option class='optemp'>" + auth + "</option>");
  $('#selauth').val(auth);
 }
}

$(document).on('click', '.postitle', function() {
 $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
 $(this).addClass('pmarked');
 givemestuff();
});
```

```css
.postitle{
cursor:pointer;
}

.pmarked{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='earth'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='moon'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='sun'>lorem ipsum</div>
<br>
<select id='selauth'>
<option>moon</option>
<option>sun</option>
</select>
```

on page load everything works fine.
i.e. `option-earth` is added to `selauth` and it is selected automatically.

Click on next `postitle` also works - `option-earth` is removed...

But click again on first `postitle` - `selauth` is blank, i.e. no option is selected, i.e. `option-earth` is not added!

What is wrong?

Comment: The code serves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove any temporary option from select then you also need to remove it from array `names`. 
So, I have remove temp option value from array `names` by conditionally :

```
if($('.optemp').length == 0){   
    names.splice(names.indexOf(auth), 1 );
}
```

```js
var names = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#selauth option').each(function(){
  names.push($(this).text());
 });
});

function givemefirst() {
 $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
 $('.postitle').eq(0).addClass('pmarked');
 givemestuff();
}

givemefirst();

function givemestuff() {
 let obj = $('.pmarked');
 let auth = obj.attr('data-auth');
  if($('.optemp').length == 0){   
    names.splice(names.indexOf(auth), 1 );
  }
  $('.optemp').remove();
  
 if (names.includes(auth)) {
  $('#selauth').val(auth);
 }
 else {
  $('#selauth').append("<option class='optemp'>" + auth + "</option>");
  $('#selauth').val(auth);
 }
}

$(document).on('click', '.postitle', function() {
 $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
 $(this).addClass('pmarked');
 givemestuff();
});
```

```css
.postitle{
cursor:pointer;
}

.pmarked{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='earth'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='moon'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='sun'>lorem ipsum</div>
<br>
<select id='selauth'>
<option>moon</option>
<option>sun</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works, but can you explain, pls. why is important to add `val='"+auth+"'...`

Comment: @blueSky , You can remove this `val='"+auth+"'` now.
I have just removed one line from your code that is `$('.optemp').remove();`

Comment: No, pls don't I need to remove it and add it again only if it is not in `array-names`

Comment: Yes, it works again, thanks, but I can't see why it works now and doesn't work in my case, pls any word of explanation.

Comment: @blueSky I added explanation in top of my answer.

Comment: But I think array `names` is a constant, established on page load. It should not change itself by clicking on `postitle`. Why I need to remove any from that array? Or, maybe it is changed somehow?

Comment: because you are checking condition with the array `if (names.includes(auth)) {}`

Comment: Yes, but `checking` doesn't mean - `add`. Where is the moment `optemp` is added to `names` so I need to remove it?

Comment: @blueSky But If it's worked by removing value from array then it's great...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change it to this:

DEMO: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/RJYapd

```
var names = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selauth option').each(function(){
        names.push($(this).text());
    });
});

function givemefirst() {
    $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
    $('.postitle').eq(0).addClass('pmarked');
    givemestuff();
}

givemefirst();

function givemestuff() {
    let obj = $('.pmarked');
  $('.optemp').remove();
    let auth = obj.attr('data-auth');  
    if ($("#selauth option[value='"+auth+"']").length > 0) {
        $('#selauth').val(auth);
    }
    else {
        $('#selauth').append("<option class='optemp' value='"+auth+"'>" + auth + "</option>");
        $('#selauth').val(auth);
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.postitle', function() {
    $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
    $(this).addClass('pmarked');
    givemestuff();
});
```

Comment: In that case I have two same options inside `selauth`. That's not allowed.

Comment: but why do you need condition?

Comment: long story short - I need dinamically add and remove options of `selauth`.

Comment: now `option-earth` (optemp) is not removed by clicking on `postitle - moon`

Comment: `if (names.includes(auth) && auth != 'earth') {` - `earth` is not a constant but a variable

Comment: for dynamic values, you need to use values in option, check demo!!

Comment: `for dynamic values, you need to use values in option,` - I see, but can you say - why?. Why the text of an option is not more it's value?

Comment: its good idea to set value of option and use that. Also, you can set same as text!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code with very small changes in your code.

**Changes made -**

1. In function, givemestuff(), do not remove $(.optemp). Remove the
   class only.
2. In the same function, under else section, push the auth into *names*
   array.

With this code, you are free to add only required *option* under *select* element.

Let me know for any further query.

```
var names = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selauth option').each(function(){
        names.push($(this).text());
    });
});

function givemefirst() {
    $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
    $('.postitle').eq(0).addClass('pmarked');
    givemestuff();
}

givemefirst();

function givemestuff() {
    let obj = $('.pmarked');
        $('.optemp').removeClass('optemp');
    let auth = obj.attr('data-auth');
    if (names.includes(auth)) {
        $('#selauth').val(auth);
    }
    else {
        $('#selauth').append("<option class='optemp'>" + auth + "</option>");
        $('#selauth').val(auth);
                names.push(auth);
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.postitle', function() {
    $('.pmarked').removeClass('pmarked');
    $(this).addClass('pmarked');
    givemestuff();
});
```

```css
.postitle{
cursor:pointer;
}

.pmarked{
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='earth'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='moon'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle' data-auth='sun'>lorem ipsum</div>
<br>
<select id='selauth'>
<option>moon</option>
<option>sun</option>
</select>
```